# The difference between instance variable and property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, instance-variables

The difference between instance variable and property in Objective-C?
Please answer guys.

Comment: Don't ask without searching on internet. There are already hundreds of talk on this.

Answer (score 0):

Property has getters and setters automatically. For instance variable you should write getter and setter manually.